# how to use startActivityForResult() with a singletask activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In our requirement, we need to refresh A activity after B activity finish.
but B activity is set as singletask.
Is there any flag or another API can fulfill this requirement?

thank you.

Comment: Single task activity ? what do you mean i can not get it. can you tell me what is that?

Comment: its mean android:launchMode="singleTop"

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the only way to achieve the thing you want - using broadcasting: when B has been finished - send broadcast and in A catch it.

btw, is it so necessary to use singletask?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set some result to activity A from Activity 2 then you have two options

1) If you have one activity already in `activity stack` then you have two options
    1=> Use `startActivityFroResult()` and set result back to calling activity
    2=> Make fields in activity A as `public static` and assign values from activityB and `onResume()` of ActivityA refresh view of ActivityA

2) If you have `not ActivityA in activity stack` then just pass the necessary values with the intent and from ActivityA `onCreate()` method fetch all values from intent and load view